# Difference in passing a double pointer to a function in C and C++

Tags: c, warnings

In parseFunc() if I call loadFunc() by passing &tIpArray, it compiles fine when using C as the compile(in onlinegdb.com) but complains as below on a later version of C compiler(gcc-bin/4.9.4/gcc) at work.

Error at work is similar to what I see when I compile when using language as C++ in onlinegdb. Can someone tell me why the 4.9.4 gcc C compiler doesn't like the & and what is the right way to handle this?

```
/******************************************************************************

Welcome to GDB Online.
GDB online is an online compiler and debugger tool for C, C++, Python, PHP, Ruby, 
C#, VB, Perl, Swift, Prolog, Javascript, Pascal, HTML, CSS, JS
Code, Compile, Run and Debug online from anywhere in world.

*******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _MyStruct
{
    char string[72];
}MyStruct;

int loadFunc(MyStruct** ipData, int counter)
{
    MyStruct **currentVal = ipData;

    MyStruct *ipPtr = NULL;

    printf("%p\n", currentVal);

    for(int i=0; i<counter; i++)
    {
        ipPtr = currentVal[i];
        printf("Line-%d - %s - %p\n", i+1, ipPtr->string, ipPtr);
    }
}

int parseFunc()
{
        MyStruct*   tIPArray[3];

        for(int i=0; i< 3; i++)
        {
            tIPArray[i] = 0;
            tIPArray[i] = (MyStruct*) calloc(1, sizeof(MyStruct));
            snprintf(tIPArray[i]->string, 72, "Test-String-%d", i+101);         
        }        

        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            printf("Line-%d %p-%p- %s\n", i+1, &tIPArray[i], tIPArray[i], tIPArray[i]->string);
        }

        // call the load/ print loadFunc
        loadFunc(&tIPArray, 3);
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    parseFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

> Below is the error I get at work
>
> ```
> error: passing argument 1 of 'loadFunc' from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]
>    loadFunc(&tIPArray, 3);
> note: expected 'struct MyStruct **' but argument is of type 'struct MyStruct * (*)[(sizetype)((int)((short unsigned int)getMaxAddressObjects() / 4u))]'
>  int loadFunc(MyStruct **ipData, int counter)
> ```

Below error when building this in onlinegdb.com as C++ file

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int parseFunc()’:
> main.cpp:49:38: error: cannot convert ‘MyStruct * (*)[3] {aka MyStruct * (*)[3]}’ to ‘MyStruct ** {aka MyStruct **}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int loadFunc(MyStruct **, int)’
>      loadFunc(&tIPArray, 3);
> ```

Comment: Please re-format your question. Currently the mark-up makes a little sense.

Comment: R Sahu, the code is working code. The compile error happens when I pass it as &tIPArray. I'll update the code for clarity.

Comment: @KingkongJnr The compile error is correct. The type of `tIPArray` in an expression is conversion to temporary pointer to base element. Since the elements are `MyStruct *`, a pointer to that would be `MyStruct **`.  Therefore `loadFunc(&tIPArray, 3);` is wrong; it should be `loadFunc(tIPArray, 3);` The error says as much, and goes on to specifically tell you the difference in types and thus the conflict. That they resolve to the same address is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This declaration ...

> ```
>         MyStruct*   tIPArray[3];
> ```

declares `tIPArray` as an array of 3 `MyStruct *`.  Therefore, `&tIPArray` is a pointer to such an array, its type is `MyStruct *(*)[3]`, just as the error message says.  This is not the same type as `MyStruct **`, which is the expected type of the function argument.

You can instead pass an explicit pointer to the first element ...

```
        loadFunc(&tIPArray[0], 3);
```

... but it would be more idiomatic to just omit the `&`, since ordinary conversion of array to pointer ("decay" of the array) produces a pointer of the correct type and value:

```
        loadFunc(tIPArray, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it can be clearer if we use `typedef MyStruct* StrPtr;`. Then your example becomes:

```
void foo(StrPtr* bar);

StrPtr array[4];
```

First, let look at this call:

```
foo(array);
```

Array is of type `StrPtr[4]`, not `StrPtr*`. Ideally this would call `foo(StrPtr bar[4])` but there's no such function. The next best match is that arrays can decay to pointers to their elements = `StrPtr*` and luckily there's `foo(StrPtr* bar)` function so the call is valid.

Now, what is type of this expression?

```
&array;
```

Well, again array is of type `StrPtr[4]` so this must be a pointer to that type = `StrPtr(*)[4]`. Same "weird" syntax as for function pointers.

At last, take this call:

```
foo(&array);
```

We now know that this would like to call `foo(StrPtr(*bar)[4])` and again there's no such function. So what can compiler do? `&array` is not an array, it's a pointer and pointers cannot decay to anything. Hmm, what now? Well, in C any pointer can be passed to another no matter the type. Dereferencing such pointer is another thing. So, this call is valid and calls `foo(StrPtr* bar)` as there's no other candidate. Success? No, any decent compiler should warn against this, even better turning those warnings into errors using `-Wincompatible-pointer-types` or even forbid all warnings with `-Werror` as you did.

So, the take away is that correct call is `foo(array);`.